# Make col class of <div> responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I make my col class of my `<div>` element responsive?

I would like the text content and the image be shown side by side. The image should go down only when the screen size is too small. Like mobile screens.

Below is a part of my HTML and CSS code for the image and the content:

```css
.content-style {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: cursive;
}

#image-position {
    width: 40%;
    border-radius: 700px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="column-left">
        <p class="content-style"> Hola! I am Gaurav, I work at Torry Harris as an IFW Support Analyst. I love coding and I wanna build my career in a lot of fields. If I could name some right way, they would be, Web Development, SOA Technologies, Automation Testing and a lot more. Apart from these I also love to read. The genre of my liking are Fiction, Adventurous, and Epics. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="column-right">
        <img align="right" id="image-position" class="img-responsive" src="https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-24133659af6ec93b462b1ec32a3312e6-c" alt="Goku's Image">
    </div>
</div>
<hr/>
</div>
```

[image: Snapshot of the webpage]

Comment: Can you use [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)?  Otherwise you will need to use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) yourself.

Comment: I am using boostrap @PM77-1

Comment: I added an answer using Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are OK to use Bootsrap, you can use this updated snippet. Otherwise, you will need to implement your own media rules.

```css
     .content-style
    {
      font-size: 20px;
      font-family: cursive;
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 992px){
     .content-style{
      float: left;
     }
     
     #image-position{
       float: right;
     }
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 992px){
     #image-position{
       margin: auto;
     }
    }
        
    
    
    #image-position{
      width:40%;
      border-radius: 700px;
    }
    
    .row.someDiv{
      margin-left: 0px;
      margin-right: 0px;
    }
    
    .row.someDiv .col-md-4{
       padding-right: 0px;
     margin-right: 0px;
    }
    
    .row.someDiv .col-md-8{
       padding-left: 0px;
     margin-left: 0px;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <div class="row someDiv">
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <p class="content-style">Hola! I am Gaurav, I work at Torry
    Harris as an IFW Support Analyst. I love coding and I wanna build my
    career in a lot of fields. If I could name some right way, they
    would be, Web Development, SOA Technologies, Automation Testing and
    a lot more. Apart from these I also love to read. The genre of my
    liking are Fiction, Adventurous, and Epics.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
   <img id="image-position" class="img-responsive"
    src="https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-24133659af6ec93b462b1ec32a3312e6-c"
    alt="Goku's Image">
  </div>
 </div>
 <hr />
```

Comment: Hi @orabis. Thank you for your help. It worked to some extent. but I want the image to be positioned in the extreme right and the content to fill the area between the left side of the page till the image. I have added the snapshot of the current page to my question. Please take a look at it.

Comment: You mean align left? I took a look at your screenshot, and made the required change that, hopefully, will be what you are looking for. I can see that you are more interested in giving more space to your image, so I gave 4 spans for the text and 8 spans to the image. Let me know if there is still something  required.

Comment: Hi @orabis thank you for your quick response, I want the image to be positioned in the  extreme right. Nothing to do with the allotment of space for it. As you can see in the screen shot, the image and the text are pulled to the left. I want the image to be in the right most corner. I tried using setting the align attribute for the image as align="right", but it didn't work.

Comment: I made some changes so when the width is small, and the image and text are aligned vertically, the image will be centered. This is instead of pulling the image to the right while there is no text in the same line with it.

Comment: How did it go?.

Comment: I wanted the image to be in the right. after the content. I tried adding a new class to the div element of the image.
div.relative{
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}
The image is going to the right but under the text content. can you help me arranging the image and the text content so that they are positioned side by side? The image must be in the right most corner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162140/discussion-between-gaurav-thantry-and-orabis).

Answer (score 1):

For a simple 2-column layout, consider using the `display: flex` property for the parent element and `flex: 1` property for the child elements. To improve the responsive layout on smaller screens, use a media query to change the display type back to 'block'.

```css
 <style>
     .wrapper { 
         max-width: 480px;
         margin: 0 auto;
     }
     .wrapper .row { 
         display: flex;
         /* extra code if you want to center the child elements */
         align-items: center;
         justify-content: center;
     }
     .wrapper .row > .column-left { 
         flex: 1; 
     }
     .wrapper .row > .column-right { 
         flex: 1; 
     }
     .wrapper .img-responsive { 
         max-width: 100%; 
         float: initial;
     }
     @media screen and (max-width:600px) {
         .wrapper .row { 
             display: block;
         }
     }
 </style>
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="row">
              <div class="column-left">
                    <p class="content-style"> Hola! I am Gaurav, I work at Torry Harris as an IFW Support Analyst. I love coding and I wanna build my career in a lot of fields. If I could name some right way, they would be, Web Development, SOA Technologies, Automation Testing and a lot more. Apart from these I also love to read. The genre of my liking are Fiction, Adventurous, and Epics.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="column-right">
                    <img align="right" id="image-position" class="img-responsive" src="https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-24133659af6ec93b462b1ec32a3312e6-c" alt="Goku's Image">
              </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: damn.. so flawless :thumbup

Answer (score 0):

Can you use floats? Try this:

```
.column-left{
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    width:50%;
}

.column-right{
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
            width:50%;
}
```

by making the images inline-block and setting width to 50% they will both display in the same line. Floating makes them go as far left or right as they can.

Comment: This will have the same behavior with small screen width. What is asked here is to make sure that elements will be vertically aligned when the screen width is small, similarity to Bootstrap for instanceI.

Comment: No problem. Define small. What  you need is a media query that toggles to display:block when "size is less than small"

Comment: Yes, we will need is a media query; this is actually what I was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style>
  .content-style {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: cursive;
  }
  
  .right {
    width: 49%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background-image: url('https://img1.ibxk.com.br/2014/06/13/13145034906534.jpg?w=480&h=560&mode=crop');
    min-height: 200px;
    height: 30%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    border-radius: 700px;
  }
  
  .left {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 30%;
    padding-top: -top: 10px;
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .breaker {
      clear: both;
      display: inline;
      height: 100px;
    }
    .left {
      clear: both;
      display: inline;
    }
    .right {
      clear: both;
      display: inline;
    }
  }
</style>
<div style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="left">
    <p> Hola! I am Gaurav, I work at Torry Harris as an IFW Support Analyst. I love coding and I wanna build my career in a lot of fields. If I could name some right way, they would be, Web Development, SOA Technologies, Automation Testing and a lot more.
      Apart from these I also love to read. The genre of my liking are Fiction, Adventurous, and Epics. </p>
  </div>
  <div class="breaker"><br></div>
  <div class="right">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```